# Как добавиться тень под кнопку в Tkinter'e?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, button, python-2.7

Как добавить тень под  кнопку в Tkinter, чтобы получилось, как будто кнопка над поверхностью? Как кнопки в tvml, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить Label черного цвета под кнопкой:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Some text')
button.place(x=0, y=0)

root.update()  # обновляем окно, чтобы размер кнопки обновился

shadow = tk.Label(root, background='black')
# Делаем размеры тени совпадающими с размерами кнопки, располагаем с небольшим смещением
shadow.place(x=10, y=10, width=button.winfo_width(), height=button.winfo_height())
shadow.lower(button)  # помещаем тень под кнопкой

root.mainloop()
```